# Windows Terminal/Powershell Intellisense

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal, autocomplete, intellisense

I'm not sure if these are the correct terms, but in some tutorial videos I've watched, I've seen terminal "auto-completing" some commands in some sort of intellisense. For example, one starts typing "npx cre", the terminal auto-completes with "npx create-react-app", but the remaining characters a bit greyed out, to accept or not the auto-completion.
Is this feature exclusive to macOS or Linux terminals? I'm currently using the new windows terminal app, but I couldn't find a way to enable this.

Thanks so much if you someone can clarify this.

Comment: It's up to each shell and possibly programs running inside them to provide such a feature, which I would call in-line auto-completion (not sure if there's an official name). PowerShell, via its PSReadLine module, doesn't offer this feature yet, but it looks like it's being worked on - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/687

Comment: The demo author, could have also made specific customizations (WT settings, PSReadline, etc.), add-on modules, etc to get that. By design WT, and PSterm (console host, ISE and VSCode) have tab complete for cmdlets (properties, switches, etc.). However, this is not the level of IntelliSense you see in the PowerShell editors (ISE, VSCore) when using the editor pane. This is changing with PSv7.1 and beyond. [PowerShell 7.1- A Next-Gen Shell - Steve Lee and Jason Helmick - PSCONFEU 2020 - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhr-1KOZvFo)

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/14367 right arrow works

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's the 2.1 version of Psreadline:  [PSReadLine 2.1.0 - PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSReadLine/2.1.0)  It autocompletes using the command history file.  It works in powershell 5.1 and comes with powershell 7.

Actually PSReadLine is up to version 2.2.6.  To turn it on, put "Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource History" in your $profile.

```
Install-Module -Name PSReadLine -force
```

[Predictive IntelliSense · Issue #1468 · PowerShell/PSReadLine](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/1468)

Make sure that you use the right arrow to "activate" the auto completion suggestion. Using the Tab displays another behavior.

Comment: thanks work in windows 11 22h2 terminal as well

Comment: This feature was added to the Windows Terminal recently and now it has two conflicting autocomplete features. It shows one thing and you press tab and get another! Bizarre, confusing, and frustrating.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/14367 right arrow works

Comment: is that still the current way to go?